# Knex - missing FROM-clause entry for table "tableName"

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to make an update on my persistent storage (postgres) using knex but it keeps giving me this error
`missing FROM-clause entry for table "requests"`
and it's been hard to tell why as I have included a `from` clause.

Here is the query:

```js
knex("requests")
      .where("requests.collectionId", "collections.id")
      .where("collectionTags.collectionId", "collections.id")
      .whereRaw(`collections."startTime" > now() - interval '1 minute'`)
      .from("collections", "collectionTags")
      .where("requests.state", "ACCEPTED")
      .where("requests.memberId", 222)
      .where("collectionTags.tagId", 11)
      .update({ status: "CANCELLED" })
      .returning("id");
```

What changes do I need to do to make this work please?

I would prefer to use knex to do this as opposed to using raw sql.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the `requests` table is not included in your FROM clause but you are trying to reference it in your WHERE clauses.

The reason this is happening is due to how you are using the `.from` function. Basically your `.from` function call is overwriting the implicit "from" you get by including the tablename as an argument to the `knex` function call.

From the knex doc: https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#from

> Specifies the table used in the current query, **replacing the current
> table name if one has already been specified**

You originally add the `requests` table to your FROM clause when you do `knex('requests')`. However later on you are overwriting this when you do `.from("collections", "collectionTags")`

Basically you want to include all of them in a single `.from()` call.